# Non-isentropic expansion of an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, gas

Consider an ideal gas in a piston, where the piston head moves to increase the volume of the piston from $V_1$ to $V_2$. If the piston head moves and  $v\ll v_s$ with $v_s$ the speed of sound in the material, then we're in the isentropic regime, entropy stays constant to a good approximation, and $V T^{c_V}$ stays constant to a good approximation. If the piston head moves with velocity $v\gg v_s$, this is essentially free expansion, and so $T$ stays constant and the entropy changes $$S_2=S_1+N\log(V_2/V_1).$$ But what about if the piston head moves with some intermediate velocity? Where would I learn more about this type of dynamics?

I imagine that one would have to consider the molecular dynamics of the situation, but I'm wondering what types of theoretical or empirical tools are available. Fine, a physical piston head moving at 500m/s isn't that realistic, but I imagine such situations must be common in shockwaves or explosive decompression. [This stackexchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537120/230863) makes me think that I should look try to estimate $$\Delta S=\int (p_{gas}-p_{piston})dV/T$$ through molecular dynamics considerations, but it would be nice to have a road map first!

Comment: "If the piston head moves and  $v\ll v_s$ with $v_s$ the speed of sound in the material, then we're in the adiabatic expansion regime, entropy stays constant", Not so. entropy is generated unless the piston moves infinitesimally slowly, i.e $v\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @BobD Fine, agreed, but with what relation? Is it $O(v)$ as $v\to 0$ or is it flatter like $O(v^2)$ or $O(\exp(-v_s/v))$?

Comment: I only wanted to comment on reversibility, not answer the question

Comment: @BobD my expectation is that $\Delta S=0$ to a very good approximation for a wide range of piston velocities around $v/v_s\ll 1$. If that's incorrect, then a statement about how much it's incorrect by is needed! Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with calling it the adiabatic regime.

Comment: Again, the piston must quasi -statically, I.e. $v\rightarrow 0$ to be reversible

Comment: Are you thinking that if $Q=0$ then $\Delta S=0$?

Comment: @BobD Oops, I corrected my post where I wrote "non-adiabatic" when I meant "non-isentropic", maybe that's the cause of some confusion. I also updated my wording to add "to a good approximation". Other than that, my wording stays just fine! If $\Delta S(v)$ is the change in entropy after this experiment, we know $\Delta S(0)=0$ and $\Delta S(\infty)=N\log(V_2/V_1)$. You're saying $\Delta S(\epsilon)$ is not strictly zero, but if it were zero to all orders in a Taylor expansion around $v=0$ I'd say that's a bit of a nitpick. It's possible I'm missing something, I did misuse the word adiabatic.

Comment: “If the piston head moves and  $v\ll v_s$ with $v_s$ the speed of sound in the material, then we're in the isentropic regime “. That is incorrect.  Only when $v\rightarrow 0$ is the adiabatic expansion isentropic.

Comment: Isentropic means $\Delta S=0$. Not $\Delta S\approx 0$. Reversible processes are  intended to be idealizations. All real processes are irreversible. If we start saying a process is reversible if $\Delta S\approx 0$ who’s to say how close to zero is close enough? How much less than the speed of sound is slow enough? The definition of reversible becomes opinion based.

Comment: It's true that all real processes are irreversible and finite $v$ means that it's certainly not true that $\Delta S = 0$.  But regardless of the terminology, I think that David's question is about where and how that picture breaks down, quantitatively, and it's an important one to be asking in order to understanding the boundaries of equilibrium thermodynamics.

Comment: @RokasVeitas I’m not opposed to the idea of approaching reversibility,  just establishing some  non quantitative value of speed, such as $v\ll v_s$ , for which one can say a process is reversible.

Comment: @BobD Ok, sure—there's no finite speed at which it's reversible.  But it's reasonable to ask about the behavior of $\Delta S(v = \epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @RokasVeitas isn’t it sufficient to say that $\Delta S(v=\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @BobD That is true!  But it's worthwhile to ask about the asymptotic behavior—what is the value $\alpha$ such that $\Delta S(v = \epsilon) \sim \epsilon^\alpha$? (if it's even well-described by a power law)

Comment: @RokasVeitas Yes,  I suppose so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150523/discussion-between-bob-d-and-rokas-veitas).

Answer (score 4):

If you restrict your question to a shock wave *without* looking
into the details of molecular dynamics, a simple analysis can be given
regarding the nonlinear entropy production rate through the shock's
front. Below I summarize the results from Section 11 of the classic
paper of [Tolman and Fine](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4392/1/TOLrmp48.pdf).

Tolman & Fine assume that, on the passage of gas through a shock
wavefront, there will be sudden changes in the density $\rho$ of
the gas, in its pressure $p$, in its internal energy $\epsilon$
per unit mass, and in its velocity $u$ as measured relative to the
wavefront and as positive in the direction of motion through it.

Applying the principles of the conservation of mass, of momentum,
and of energy to the passage before (1) and after (2) the shock, one
gets in steady state that:

\begin{equation}
\rho_{1}u_{1}=\rho_{2}u_{2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
p_{1}+\rho_{1}u_{1}^{2}=p_{2}+\rho_{2}u_{2}^{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
p_{1}u_{1}+\rho_{1}u_{1}\big(\epsilon_{1}+\tfrac{1}{2}u_{1}^{2}\big)=p_{2}u_{2}+\rho_{2}u_{2}\big(\epsilon_{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}u_{2}^{2}\big)\tag{3}
\end{equation}

These Eq. (1), (2), (3) are to be taken together with the thermal and caloric equations of
state per unit mass for an ideal gas as

\begin{equation}
p_{1}=\rho_{1}r^{*}T_{1},p_{2}=\rho_{2}r^{*}T_{2} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{1}=c_{v}T_{1},\epsilon_{2}=c_{v}T_{2} \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Let $M$ be the molar mass, then $r^{*}=\frac{R}{M}$ is the gas constant
per unit mass and set $r=\frac{f}{2}r^{*}$, then $C_{v}=\frac{f}{2}\frac{m}{M}R=\frac{f}{2}mr^{*}=mr$ is the heat capacity of the ideal gas, or $c_{v}=\frac{f}{2}\frac{1}{M}R=\frac{f}{2}r^{*}=r$ is the heat capacity per unit mass, $c_{p}=c_{v}+r^{*}$, the adiabatic ratio is $\gamma=\frac{c_{p}}{c_{v}}=1+\frac{r^{*}}{c_{v}}.$
The thermal equation of state is $pV=\frac{m}{M}RT=mr^{*}T$, and therefore
$p=\rho r^{*}T$; the caloric equation of state is $\epsilon=c_{v}T=\frac{f}{2}r^{*}T$, where $f$ is the degrees of freedom.

Now Tolman & Fine assume that before and after the passage through
the shock front the gas is essentially in equilibrium and the passage
is so fast that it can be taken to be *adiabatic*$^*$. Since $\rho u$
is the mass flow rate per unit time and per unit cross section, the
entropy increase per unit time across the shock can be calculated
by multiplying $\rho_{1}u_{1}$ with the entropy increase per unit
mass $\Delta S_{12}^{*}$.
Since $$TdS^{*}=c_{v}dT+pd\left(\frac{V}{m}\right)\\=c_{v}dT+d\left(p\frac{V}{m}\right)-\frac{V}{m}dp=(c_{v}+r^{*})dT-\frac{r^{*}T}{p}dp$$

\begin{align*}
TdS^{*} & =c_{v}dT+pdv=c_{v}dT+d\left(p\frac{V}{m}\right)-\frac{V}{m}dp\\
= & (c_{v}+r^{*})dT-\frac{r^{*}T}{p}dp\\
dS^{*}= & c_{p}d\ln T-r^{*}d\ln p\\
\Delta S_{12}^{*} & =c_{p}\ln\frac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}-r^{*}\ln\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}
\end{align*}
Here $\Delta S_{12}^{*}$ is the entropy difference per unit mass
between states $\left\{ p_{1},T_{1}\right\} $and $\left\{ p_{2},T_{2}\right\} $.
Thus the irreversible entropy production per unit *time* and per unit *volume* across the shock is:

\begin{align}
\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt} & =\rho_{1}u_{1}\Delta S_{12}^{*}=\rho_{1}u_{1}\left(c_{p}\ln\frac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}-r^{*}\ln\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}

===========================================

Note added on the asymptotics of $\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt}$ as $u_{1} \to u_{min}$
(nasty, indeed).

From (1):
\begin{equation}
u_{2}=u_{1}\frac{\rho_{1}}{\rho_{2}}\tag{7}
\end{equation}
substitute (7) into (2) and express $u_{2}^{2}$; also denote $\tau=\frac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}$ and $\xi=\frac{\rho_{2}}{\rho_{1}}$,
then:

\begin{equation}
u_{1}^{2}=T_{1}r^{*}\frac{\xi(\xi\tau-1)}{\xi-1}\tag{8}
\end{equation}

Now substitute the same (7) into (3), and again express $u_{1}^{2}$:

\begin{equation}
u_{1}^{2}=T_{1}c_{p}\frac{2\xi^{2}(\tau-1)}{\xi^{2}-1}\tag{9}
\end{equation}

Now equate (8) and (9):
\begin{equation}
u_{1}^{2}=T_{1}r^{*}\frac{\xi(\xi\tau-1)}{\xi-1}=T_{1}c_{p}\frac{2\xi^{2}(\tau-1)}{\xi^{2}-1} \tag{10}
\end{equation}
and simplify the common factors on both sides:
\begin{equation}
r^{*}(\xi\tau-1)=c_{p}\frac{2\xi(\tau-1)}{\xi+1}\tag{11}
\end{equation}
Now rearrange and express $\tau$ in (10):
\begin{equation}
\tau=\frac{k-1}{k-\xi}\tag{12}
\end{equation}
where $k=\frac{c_{p}}{r^{*}}\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}=g\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}$,
$g=\frac{c_{p}}{r^{*}}$, and in this notation

\begin{equation}
u_{1}=\sqrt{{T_{1}r^{*}}}\sqrt{\frac{\xi(\xi\tau-1)}{\xi-1}}\tag{13}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt} & =\rho_{1}u_{1}\left(c_{p}\ln\frac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}-r^{*}\ln\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}\right) \tag{14}\\
= & \rho_{1}u_{1}\left(c_{p}\ln\tau-r^{*}\ln\frac{\rho_{2}r^{*}T_{2}}{\rho_{1}r^{*}T_{1}}\right) \tag{15}\\
= & \rho_{1}u_{1}\left(c_{p}\ln(\tau)-r^{*}\ln(\xi\tau)\right)\tag{16}\\
= & \frac{\rho_{1}}{r^{*}}u_{1}\left((g-1)\ln(\tau)-\ln(\xi)\right) \tag{17}
\end{align}

Thermodynamic equilibrium is represented by $T_{2}=T_{1},\rho_{2}=\rho_{1}$,
so we have $u_{1}\approx u_{min}$,here $u_{min}$is the minimum velocity
with which the shock travels in the fluid, that is when $T_{2}\approx T_{1},\rho_{2}\approx\rho_{1}$, or $\tau\approx1,\xi\approx1$. Therefore, we set $\xi=1+x$ with $\mathcal{O}(x^{4})=0,$ and expand (12) in a Taylor series with the result

\begin{equation}
\tau=1+\frac{1}{g-1}x-\frac{1}{2}\frac{g-2}{(g-1)^{2}}x^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{2g^{2}-5g+4}{(g-1)^{3}}x^{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{4}) \tag{18}
\end{equation}
and its logarithm:
\begin{equation}
\ln(\tau)=\frac{1}{g-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{6g^{2}-9g+4}{(g-1)^{2}}x^{3}\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^{4}) \tag{19}
\end{equation}
where $g=\frac{c_{p}}{r^{*}}=1+\frac{c_{v}}{r^{*}}$ and the term
in parentheses (17) becomes:

\begin{align}
c_{p}\ln(\tau)-r^*\ln(\xi\tau) & =c_{v}\ln(\tau)-r^*\ln(\xi) \tag{20}\\
= & c_{v}\frac{1}{g-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{6g^{2}-9g+4}{(g-1)^{2}}x^{3}\right)\tag{21}\\
- & r^{*}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{3}x^{3}\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^{4}) \tag{22}\\
= & r^{*}\frac{1}{12}\frac{g(2g-1)}{(g-1)^{2}}x^{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{4}) \tag{23}
\end{align}

Now we apply the Taylor expansion to (13):
\begin{align}
u_{1} & =\sqrt{r^{*}T_{1}}\sqrt{\frac{g}{g-1}}\left(1+\frac{2g-1}{4(g-1)}x\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^{2})\tag{24}\\
= & \sqrt{\frac{c_{p}}{c_{v}}r^{*}T_{1}}\left(1+\frac{2c_{p}-r^{*}}{4(c_{p}-r^{*})}x\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^{2}) \tag{25}
\end{align}

By the Newton-Laplace equation, the velocity of sound at temperature $T_{1}$ is $\hat{u_{s}}=\sqrt{\frac{c_{p}}{c_{v}}r^{*}T_{1}}$, and since $c_{p}>r^{*}$ the minimum entrance velocity is just the sound velocity. This minimum velocity corresponding to $x=0$, that is when $\rho_{1}=\rho_{2}$:

\begin{equation}
u_{min}=\hat{u_{s}} \tag{26}
\end{equation}

Finally, use (24) in (17), note that
$$\frac{g(2g-1)}{(g-1)^{2}}=\frac{c_{p}}{r^{*}}\frac{(2c_{p}-r^{*})}{(c_{p}-r^{*})^{2}}\\=\frac{(r^{*}+2c_{v})c_{p}}{c_{v}^{2}}$$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt}=\rho_{1}u_{1}\left(r^{*}\frac{1}{12}\frac{g(2g-1)}{(g-1)^{2}}x^{3}\right)+\mathcal{O}(x^{5}) \tag{27}
\end{equation}

with $h_{1}=\frac{2c_{p}-r^{*}}{4(c_{p}-r^{*})}$ and $h_{0}=\frac{(r^{*}+2c_{v})c_{p}}{12c_{v}^{2}}$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt}=\left(h_{0}\right)\left(r^{*}\rho_{1}\hat{u_{s}}\right)\left(1+h_{1}x\right)x^{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{5}) \tag{28}
\end{equation}

showing a 3rd order asymptotic dependence, $\frac{dS_{i}}{dt}=\mathcal{O}\left(x^{3}\right)$
of the entropy production flux on the excess velocity
$u_{1}-u_{min} = h_{1}x = \mathcal{O}(x)$ over the speed of sound.

As a crude check on the result, note that $c_{p}-r>0$ for all gases, and thus in the formula the leading term is positive in accordance
with the postivity of the entropy production, $\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt}>0$.

The physical dimensions of the various parameters are as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
[r^{*}] &=\mathrm{\frac{J}{kg\cdot K}} \\
[u] &=\mathrm{\frac{m}{sec}} \\
[\rho] &=\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^{3}}}\\
\left[\frac{dS_{irr}^{*}}{dt}\right] &=\mathrm{\frac{J}{kg\cdot K}}\cdot\mathrm{\frac{m}{sec}}\cdot\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^{3}}}=\mathrm{\mathrm{\frac{1}{sec}\cdot\frac{1}{m^{2}}\cdot}\frac{J}{K}}
\end{align}
$$

_____________

- This is not an isentropic process but it is still adiabatic, or
  using Pippard's term it is *adiathermal*. Pippard restricts the
  word adiabatic to mean an isentropic reversible process, he calls
  *adiathermal* a general irreversible process that is only mechanically
  coupled to its environment.

Comment: "but I have not yet analyzed the term in parentheses" it can be shown that the term is simply the entropy generated calculated by assuming a reversible path having the same initial and final pressures as the irreversible path.

Comment: Where both paths are adiabatic

Comment: Just to clarify, it’s the entropy generated per unit mass.

Comment: @Bob_D what I was referring to was that I had not yet calculated how the terms in the parentheses depend on $u$ asymptotically as $|u| \to 0$ and this is why said it "appears" to be "linear".

Comment: Got it. The units of the coefficient of the total entropy generated appear to be $(m^{2}s)^{-1}$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Bob_D remember $r$ is defined as the gas constant $R, \frac{J}{K}$ per unit mass. Therefore with  $[\rho]=\frac{kg}{m^3}, [u]=\frac{m}{sec},[r]= \frac{J}{K\cdot kg}$ so $[\frac{dS}{dt}]=[\rho u r]=\frac{J}{K\cdot sec \cdot m^2}$ entropy per unit time per unit area, that is entropy flux through the shock front.

Comment: @Bob_D to analyze the asymptotics of (6) one needs to solve the equations (1) ...(5) for $u_1$ in terms of the three free parameters, say, $T_1, p_1,  p_2$, or $T_2, T_1, p_1$ out of the ten unknowns of the 7 equations, and then let $p_2 = p_1 +\delta_T$ or $T_2=T_1+\delta_T$ for some small $\delta_p$ or $\delta_T$ (small $\delta$ is supposedly a small $u_1$ excess velocity above the front) and see how that goes in (6). Nasty.

Comment: Nasty indeed. It seems to me there should be an easier way do demonstrate this. I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: So the units on the right are $\frac{J}{K\cdot m^{2}\cdot s}$ while the units on the left are $\frac{J}{K\cdot s}$(??)

Comment: both sides have dimension $\frac{J}{K\cdot sec \cdot m^2}$. It is a one-dimensional problem, say, in $x$, homogeneous in $y,z$ so it represents the entropy production rate per unit area in $y, z$ along $x$. All the thermodynamic and mechanical variables and equations are functions in $x$.

Comment: So the units for $S_{irr}$ on the left side are $\frac{J}{K\cdot m^2}$?

Comment: @Bob_D yes, its is

Comment: @Bob_D see above the calculation for entropy production rate as function of the excess velocity, it is $\propto x^3$!